# Connect to GNOME Online Accounts with commande line

Tags: linux, command-line, fedora, gnome, bash-scripting

I write a bash script who perform post-installation configuration of my Fedora Workstation.

I would connect my Nextcloud server with GNOME Online Accounts.

Is it possible to make that with command line interface ?

Mount WebDav-Share with davfs2 command ?

davs://nextcloud_hostname/remote.php/webdav

I read the Gentoo wiki https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/GNOME/Guide/en which gives some Gnome commands but I did not find  anything.

can you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. This solution can help, I'll post it here.

1. In your actuall Gnome personnal home folder go to .config/goa-1.0

goa = Gnome Online Account

1.0 at this time maybe it will be another version for you.

2. In goa-1.0  you should find a conf file « accounts.conf » If you have added an online account in Gnome parameters. accounts.conf  example :

   ```
    [Account account_1875320154_0]
    Provider=owncloud
    Identity=username
    PresentationIdentity=username@account-url.com
    CalendarEnabled=false
    ContactsEnabled=false
    FilesEnabled=true
    Uri=https://account-url.com
    AcceptSslErrors=false
   ```
3. save and past «  accounts.conf » in your new Gnome installation. Same folder /home/user/.config/goa-1.0.
4. A network link appears automatically in Nautilus
5. Go to Gnome paramaters --> @ Online accouts a warning message prompts you to enter your online account password. Enter your password and everything should be OK.

In my case, the post-installation script will create the accounts.conf file automatically.

It may not be the best way, but it works.

Et voilà :)